# How do i retrive text from sdcard and set text view accordingly?

Tags: android, android-gridview

I am using gridview and layout inflater to display icon with text.

It should look like this:

[image]

My text file contains following data:

```
Profile 0|Profile 1|Profile 2
```

I am using following code:

```
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v;
        //String text;
        final ImageView picturesView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.icon, null);
            File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File file = new File(sdcard,"string.txt");
            //StringBuilder stext = new StringBuilder();
            TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon_text);
            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                String line;

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] columns = line.split("\\|");
                    for (String name : columns){ 

                       tv.setText(name);
                    }

                    //stext.append(line);
                    //stext.append('\n');
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                //You'll need to add proper error handling here
            }

            
            tv.setTextSize(12);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);              
            
        }
        else {
            v = convertView;
        }

}
```

I want to set the text view with the string values

```
TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon_text);
tv.setText();
```

I tried to check the columns length through `Toast.makeText(SDCardImagesActivity.this, ""+columns.length, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` but it is showing 1(5 times)

I am confused how to use columns value in tv.setText and whether columns array is correct or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code you're referencing

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v;
        if(convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.icon, null);
            TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon_text);
            tv.setText("Profile "+position);
            ImageView iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
        }
        else
        {
            v = convertView;
        }
        return v;
    }
```

Instead of this line...

```
tv.setText("Profile "+position);
```

...use the following...

```
tv.setText(columns[position]);
```

Comment: thanks mistersquonk for replying above code is generating this error: 05-30 15:56:52.894: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
05-30 15:56:52.894: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338):     at blog.android.sdcard.SDCardImagesActivity$ImageAdapter.getView(SDCardImagesActivity.java:161)

Comment: the error was coming due to some blanks line inserted in the string.txt file. Removing it renders the text below the image correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You store the content of each file line in the columns-array.
You should store this data for later, or set the text at once in your loop.

Comment: thanks dkit for replying. Can you please help me out with the code?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code to set TextView

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File file = new File(sdcard,"string.txt");



    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {


            String delimiter = "\\|";

            String[] columns = line.split(delimiter);
            for (String name : columns){ 

                tv.setText(name);
            }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        //You'll need to add proper error handling here
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: thanks deepak for replying above code doesnot display any text below image

Comment: try to print the value of name. I have tried in my side it worked after that only i post the code.

Comment: i have tried to debug the application(added breakpoint at tv.setText(name). It shows the value correctly that is runs for 5 times but in the end it doesnot show anything

Comment: Just delete that file which has only three Profile names ie strings.txt and try to run to make sure that you are pointing to the correct file

Comment: I have deleted the file and then try to run the example it shows image with TextView written at the bottom of the image

Comment: If you have deleted the file. still you are getting image name that means your code points to some other file.

Comment: actually text view is defined in icon.xml  <TextView
android:id="@+id/icon_text"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="TextView"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:textColorHighlight="#656565">

Comment: There was some blank lines in the string.txt file. I have removed it but now last image text is displayed if i again use the string.txt

Answer (score 0):

You have can create the above view without creating TextView and ImageVIew. Just create a button and use drawableTop. If you want to set Profile name as per your image. create condition statements if button1 then `button.settext("Profile1")` like this.

```
<Button 
  android:id="@+id/openpdfbutton"
  android:layout_width="100dip"
  android:layout_height="60dip"
  android:text="Click"

  android:tag="@drawable/cancelfocus"
  android:drawableTop="@drawable/cancelfocus"
  />
```

Thanks
Deepak